# Wordpress Plugin Symbolic Link

Tags: wordpress, symlink, windows-server-2016

I am running a test for Wordpress with a symbolic link for a plugin on Windows Server 2016. The folder for the plugin shows up in Explorer in the plugins folder, but even with adding the Everyone permission to the link and the original folder (again, just a test - don't beat me up for that!), Wordpress still doesn't see it.

Any tips? I know multisite may be an option here, but I'm trying to do this first as a proof of concept.

Thanks!